# How to output the Cascading images or stacking images

Tags: image, matlab, drawing, matlab-figure

[image]

See above image, if there are 24 pictures, how to use MATLAB to achieve this output effect. This kind of graph often appears in papers. I define a function, but there is one line of code that cannot be implemented.

```
function h = op(file_path, pad,m,n)
img_path_list = dir(strcat(file_path,'*.jpg'));
num = length(img_path_list);%
% [m,n]=size(image);
fw=n+(num-1)*pad;
fh=m+(num-1)*pad;
h=figure('position',[0,0,fw+pad,fh+pad]);
for j = 1:num
   image_name = img_path_list(j).name;
   image =  imread(strcat(file_path,image_name));
   hold on
   pd=(j-1)*pad;
   rpl=fw-n-pd;
   rpb=fh-m-pd;
%How to specify the location of the output on the image canvas
%  set('Position',[rpl rpb n m]);
%  axes('position',[rpl rpb n m]);
   imshow (image);
end
%  h=gcf;
```

Comment: Instead of `imshow`, use the low-level `image` function, here you can specify the x and y coordinates of the pixel grid.

Comment: General question: what is the purpose of such a visualization where one cannot fully see the images on the lower layers?

Comment: To describe the extraction process

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **Xdata**, and **Ydata** in imshow() function to set the axis position of each image to display them on the same axis stacked one upon other shifted to a fixed units for each image.

**The code illustrating the procedure is given below.**

```
close all
% read the images in metrices
i1 = imread('onion.png');
i2 = imread('cameraman.tif');
i3 = imread('peppers.png');
i4 = imread('moon.tif');
i5 = imread('trees.tif');
i6 = imread('greens.jpg');
% create a cell array of the images
imgs = {i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6};

% variable to shift the position of each image
shift = 0;

% looping from 1 to length of the cell arrays
for i = 1:numel(imgs)

% display image, shifting the position to 2 units
% for each image on the same axis
imshow(imgs{i}, 'XData', [1+shift 10+shift], ...
    'YData', [1+shift 10+shift],'InitialMagnification', 400)
% hold on the axis
hold on
% increment the shift value
shift = shift + 2;
end

% set the axis limits
xlim([1 10+shift])
ylim([1 10+shift])
% hide the axis lines
axis off
```

**Sample Output**

[image]

Comment: The image size has changed

Comment: In the imshow() function try lowering the InitialMagnification value from 400 to 300 or 100.